# Вывод среза используя переменные

Tags: python-3.x

Начал учить Python для саморазвития и придумал себе задачу. Хочу написать парсер текстового документа. Я передаю строку в функцию  которая должна найти слово и после выдать заданный срез.

```
result = var[firstlang:endlang]
return result
```

После я делаю print этой функции, но почему-то ничего не выводится. Если я задам в функции числа сам:

```
var[5:10]
```

то вывод будет воспроизведен.

```
def finder(var, foundtext):
counter = len(foundtext)
firstlang = var.find(foundtext)
firstlang = firstlang+counter
endlang = 10
result = var[firstlang:endlang]
return result
```

https://pastebin.com/6YPcUnTu

```
firstlang = var.find(foundtext) + len(foundtext) 
result = var[firstlang] 
return result
```

выводит цифру как и должно, но как только добавляю срез к этой переменной так сразу выводит пустую строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предположить что оно печатает, но пустую строку, измените:

```
firstlang = var.find(foundtext)
# firstlang = firstlang+counter
# endlang = 10
endlang = firstlang + counter
```

Comment: спасибо, всё верно. endlang = firstlang + srez